# Entity Framework, and connection strings

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I'm trying to deploy my .net website to a shared hosting server. I'm getting the following error when entity framework tries to connect to the database:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Login failed for user 'PHX3\Iusr_9086819'.  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user 'PHX3\Iusr_9086819'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user
>   'PHX3\Iusr_9086819'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5061898
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234

Here is my connection string, with sensitive data removed:

```
<add name="CoreEntities" 
         connectionString="
            metadata=res://*/CoreModel.csdl|res://*/CoreModel.ssdl|res://*/CoreModel.msl;
            provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
            provider connection string='
                Data Source=*****.db.*****.hostedresource.com; 
                Initial Catalog=kshoultz;       
                integrated security=True;
                multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                App=EntityFramework; 
                User ID=*****;
                Password=*****; 
                Database=*****;
         '" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think integrated security should be false - that means not to use a user id and password.  Initial catalog is the name of the database - did they tell you the database was named kshoultz?  (Could be, I don't know any different, but if you created a database and chose a name, that's the name you want to use).  Has the password got any characters that aren't letters/numbers?  You have to encode them, for example is your password is Love&Peace you have to say Love&amp;Peace

Have you asked GoDaddy support?

Comment: Thank you. Setting integrated security to false solved the problem.

Comment: This worked. Can you explain why Integrated security had to be turned off?

Comment: @Ratan Integrated security means that the person who is running the process is recognized by sql server as a windows user.  In a shared environment, you don't want just any instance of the web server to access your database, or any other user on the machine could attach to your database - the "User" is some system account that is associated with the Web Server itself.  So instead, it has to pass in a password.  Shorter answer: "Integrated security" means you don't need a password.